# Should there be a chat link on the question page?

Tags: feature-request, questions, chat

I've run across a lot of questions where a moderator had to clean up the comments and move the discussion to chat. This seems to be a responsive solution. As a user commenting or potentially answering a question, I am surprised to find that I don't have a proactive way from the question to start a chat about it. This could be especially useful with an XY Problem sort of question I'm looking at right now when I know OP is online.

As a user I should be able to click some sort of "take this up in Chat" button that leaves a comment very similar to what a moderator's cleanup message says: "Let's continue this discussion in chat" that links to the chat room.

Comment: My only concern is that there seems to be an expiration date for chat rooms. I've run into two discussions where the chat room no longer exists.  If this option become easier to invoke I'd prefer that the chat is permanent.

Comment: @D-Klotz While that does sound less than ideal, whether I move the conversation to chat or a moderator does it, we would still run into that problem.

Comment: Chat doesn't integrate well into the UI as it stands. If we're going to do something like this, it should be a tab or popup on the page itself. This should also be a more permanent thing - not a specific option to create a chat room, but rather a chat room that's always there in case someone wants to post something which doesn't belong in the comments (with maybe a (X) modifier for when someone posts to there). But I'm more talking about comments that are entirely tangential and aren't trying to clarify the post in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue I have with this is that the "Let's continue this discussion in Chat" link is more of a symptom rather than a disease.

Let me clarify - that link automatically triggers when the threshold of comments in a given question or answer reaches a limit - I believe it's somewhere between 5 and 10 back-and-forth comments between two individuals.  Either user is then empowered to create the chat so that they can continue chatting - which is what they were doing in comments to begin with.

Chatting in comments is strongly discouraged because it implies that the question itself is poor or lacking details.  In that instance, the question should be closed until it's edited into shape with the missing details.

It also doesn't scale well to enable chat on every question posted, since people  will start to have the expectation to be able to chat to someone about their problem.  This runs **counter** to the goal of making sure they narrow down their requirements and narrow the scope of their question so that it can be answered by anyone at any time.

All of that to say:  no, I don't think this would be a useful feature.