# Hotkey to trigger the «Let's continue in chat» message, for nK rep. users

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

A new priviledge... For nK rep.

A hotkey (and/or some UI interface on a comment field focus) to trigger the automated room creation from the question/answer thread would be *sooo* nice.

I'm 18K (still a young apprentice, but used to the Stack Overflow platform's options)
Now I really don't know how to trigger a simple chat with anyone on Stack Overflow.

So, is that possible to imagine a chat request trigger between users (at least the ones interacting on a tread). If they have such a privilege?

So that's a quite wide request.
I have no idea on how to make it alive.

And the discussion about the concept itself and its impacts needs to take place first (probably is a collection of existing question/answers).

I hope no definite concrete answer in the coming hour, be cool. (lol!)

---

**EDIT**

Okay...

> Why is starting a protracted "chat" better than avoiding a long comment chain?

The question isn't why. But how.

A quick chat UI option would resolve "some" useless comment chain. 
That's for sure.

---

Say one with more than a year "active" account with good flag/close rate could do that...

Comment: Something like `@++[username autoselect]` in the comment input? The room creation function exists already ;)

Comment: Personally, if *"Let's continue in chat"* comes up, then the chain of comments is already far too long. There are cases where it does become necessary, but for me these are rare. I'm not really sold that encouraging **more** chat from comments is really the way to go. If anything that's meant to stop the comment chain from growing on questions/answers. Regularly opening back and forth discussion on Q&A does not strike me as the right direction. Comments should quickly prompt those asking to clarify information. Not join a conversation.

Comment: @NeilLunn: exactly... So before the comment chain gets far too long... A hotkey for nK rep user would help? That is my question. -- I would use it.

Comment: Closely related: [*Should there be a chat link on the question page?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374630/2751851)

Comment: @duplode: I agree about closeliness... But, the concept of a priviledge is added in my idea of the big question. SURE chatting about your life isn't relevant. --- But a quick "private" chat between (to be defined rep. level) about things like *«I think OP is talking about that thing... Which could be relevant, what you think?»* could help... Actual "trusted" users (that's a rep. level) do not actually... But it would be nice.

Comment: About the previous comment I made, I just double checked about "trusted" priviledge, which is 20K ( lol ) I do not have that yet, so I can't tell. --- My bad. --- Ok, say one with more than a year "active" account with good flag/close rate. --- And I know I complicate the sh a lot with that. Do I need to edit again or may I leave that as is?

Comment: related if not a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295219/move-comments-to-chat-on-request